# Google has more than 500k cached indexes of my ex website. How can I remove them?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, yandex-webmaster-tools

My client's ex website was full of copy-pasted news and the website's reputation was 0. Also, he wanted to get rid of Wordpress, so we re-developed his website and did not use old data.

But Google's cache is full of old page indices, more than 500k. More, new websites slugs are different than the old ones, so all the cached indices redirect to 404 pages.

I need to remove them but search console does not provide an option to handle this much indexes. What can I do?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125980/ask-google-to-remove-thousands-of-pages-from-its-index-after-cleaning-up-from-ha

Comment: Are you referring to the Google "cache" or to the URLs returned in the search results? Or both?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! We get this question often. Most people simply have not waited long enough for Google to remove the old pages. It can take up to a year depending upon how often Google visits the various pages. If Google finds enough 404s, they will begin to crawl the site more aggressively to remove old pages. This can still take months. If you can, it is always far better to return a 410. This is because a page that returns a 404 will be checked several times over a period and take longer to remove. How long has it been? Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Thank you for your concern. I'm waiting for ~2 months. Will change my 404's to 410 now. Hope they will not stay more time.

Comment: @MrWhite these pages redirects to 404 page, but apparently my 404 status code return was broken. I fixed it, now will wait few days, and change it to 410 if pages still appear

Comment: It seems like you have two problems. The first is how you are handling your 404. Do not redirect to the 404, just let the web server handle the 404 by making sure the pages do not exist. The redirect is keeping these URLs alive. Second, you will need to give Google a fair amount of time to do it's work. So if you simply let the 404s work as they should then the pages should start to disappear in a couple of months. Google should have a better way to remove pages in bulk, however, what they are doing falls within tradition. One can argue either side. Cheers!!